# cannot pass javascript data to python

Tags: javascript, python, rest

I am trying to pass data from javascript to my python API

```
$.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: "http://localhost:5000/handle_data",//url of receiver file on server

            data: my_Data, //your data

            success: function (response) {

                console.log(response);

            }, //callback when ajax request finishes

            dataType: 'text/json' //text/json...

        });
```

`my_Data` is a javascript variable

and on the server side

```
@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['GET','POST'])

def handle_data():
   print("Got data")
   data=request.form['my_Data'] // What should be here
```

I  am getting debugger over here But I am not able to read the contents.
The error is 400 Bad request

Answer (score 1):

**Pass that data into the Ajax as follow:**

```
data: { "my_Data": my_Data }
```

And this way, you will be able to get the param as follow:

```
data = request.form['my_Data']
```

[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are making an AJAX request with data type of application/json, you should handle it using request.json instead of request.form

This should work:

```
@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['GET','POST'])

def handle_data():
   print("Got data")
   data=request.json # This should be here
   print(data['my_DATA'])
   return "success"
```

Here is the corresponding AJAX call:

```
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/handle_data",
        data:JSON.stringify('my_DATA',null,'\t'),
        contentType:"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(result){

          console.log(result); //Should output success
        }});
```